# NullPointerException on FragmentHostCallback.getContext()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm facing this random crash while navigating to a Fragment via deep-link which is declared in the navigation graph file. I'm using navigation component library in my project.

**Stacktrace:**

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context androidx.fragment.app.FragmentHostCallback.getContext()' on a null object reference
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLifecycleCallbacksDispatcher.dispatchOnFragmentPreAttached(FragmentLifecycleCallbacksDispatcher.java:91)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLifecycleCallbacksDispatcher.dispatchOnFragmentPreAttached(FragmentLifecycleCallbacksDispatcher.java:96)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.attach(FragmentStateManager.java:463)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:275)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2106)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7698)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:952)
```

Comment: Can you show your code ?

Comment: @rahul-rastogi have you found a fix for this crash or steps how to reproduce it?

Comment: @AndriyD. Not yet!

Comment: Guys any luck yet?

Answer (score 1):

I was missing `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` in my Activity's onCreate. Super annoying that the error description is not more specific.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I used

```
supportFragmentManager
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.fragment_container_view, MySettingsFragment())
    .commit()
```

along with AndroidX navigation component inside Activity that hosts fragments.

You either change fragments manually with supportFragmentManager or use AndroidX navigation.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this crash, which lasted for a long time.

The app crashes when opening it using deeplink. The crash rate is around 0.2% and cannot be reproduced locally.

My temporary way to fix this problem is to disable automatic launch deeplinks.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      val curIntent = intent
      intent = null
      setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
      intent = curIntent
      // launch deeplink by yourself
      curIntent.data.let {
        findNavController(R.id.container).navUrl(it)
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error. I spent a lot of time searching for my soul. Navigation crashes when navigating back (using Google's navigation component) after navigating to a screen via a deep link, if that screen has already been opened previously. In my case, a schedule was assigned programmatically when creating a fragment:

```
  private fun setupNavGraph() {
      val Graph = navHostFragment.navController.navInflater.inflate(navGraphResId)
      startDestinationId?.let {graph.setStartDestination(it) }
      navHostFragment.navController.graph = graph
  }
```

But when going back, when restoring a fragment, this code was called again and reassigned the graph. This caused the fall.
I added the line:

```
      if (navHostFragment.navController.hasGraph()) return
```

Where hasGraph is:

```
@Suppress("INESSENTIAL_COMPARISON")
fun NavController.hasGraph() = try {
      graph != null
} catch (t: Throwable) {
      false
}
```

To prevent reassignment of an existing graph.